# Установка описания процесса запущенного через Process.Start() в диспетчере задач в C#

Tags: c#, процесс

Есть код на C# который запускает некий процесс:

```
var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo{
  FileName = file,  // Путь к приложению
  Arguments = args,
  UseShellExecute = false,
  CreateNoWindow = true,                      
};

Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Процесс запускается, но появился следующий вопрос:

**Можно как-то изменить имя и описание процесса, который мы запустили, которое показывается в диспетчере задач?**

*Сейчас в диспетчере задач в "Имя" и "Описание" отображается как name.exe*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Имя берется из названия файла, например: `program.exe`. Описание процесса берется с `[assembly: AssemblyTitle("My Title")]` (в рантайме изменить его нельзя).